# Parse AJAX response in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-parsing

I am using AJAX call in my code using Javascript.

```
function loadFacility(callback)
{
    //alert('In loadFacility');
    var xmlhttp;
    var keys=document.firstCallInformation.facilityselect.value;
    var urls="http://localhost:8080/webfdms/showFirstCallInformation.do?vitalsId=366";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
             //var some=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.log(response)
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function loadFacilityCallback(response){
if(response != null){
    //alert(response);
    console.log(response);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = response;
    document.getElementById("facilityselect").innerHTML = div.querySelectorAll("select#facilityselect");;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated my callback function. But here I received select list as [Object Nodelist]. Now how can I display in my HTML ?

In callback function I received the response as HTML now I want to parse that HTML response so that I can process it further. I am using plain javascript to do so. How to parse ajax response received as HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `DIV` element and put the HTML in it `innerHTML`. That will parse it.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = response;
```

Now you can process it in `div`, e.g. `div.querySelector(".classname")`. To get all the `<select>` tags, do:

```
var selects = div.querySelectorAll("select");
```

To put it into your webpage, you can do:

```
document.getElementById("facilityselect").innerHTML = div.querySelector("select#facilityselect").innerHTML
```

Comment: basically I want to fetch select tag from that parsed html and display it on page. and there are many select tags. so how do i fetch it ?

Comment: And I want to fetch particular select tag from the list of all select tag ?

Comment: Use a more specific selector. `select#someID`. You do it just like you would if it were in the DOM.

Comment: Please see my edit. I updated my callback function and now I am getting nodelist in return. now the problem is how to update it on my html.

Comment: You need to get the `innerHTML` of the object in your response so you can assign that to the innerHTML of your DOM. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dom='Your http response';
var wrapper=document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML=dom;
var elemContainer=wrapper.firstChild;
var elemToFind=elemContainer.querySelectorAll('option');
var facilityselect=document.getElementById('facilityselect');
facilityselect.innerHTML='';
for(var i=0, len=elemToFind.length; i < len; i++){
    facilityselect.appendChild(elemToFind[i]);
}
```

> Creating a fake div element and appending your string which contains a HTML
>   string will help.
>   To insert a DOM object in specific selector, you need to user **appendChild** method.In case you want to empty the selector and then insert the DOM then set **innerHTML** as empty **(selector.innerHTML="")** and then do the append operation.

Comment: basically I want to fetch select tag from that parsed html and display it on page. and there are many select tags. so how do i fetch it ?

Comment: Please see my edit. I updated my callback function and now I am getting nodelist in return. now the problem is how to update it on my html.

Comment: I am getting this error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88175/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-mahendra-kawde).

Comment: document.getElementById("facilityselect").appendChild(elemToFind[0]);
I tried this and checked on console there I can see my updated result. but when I go to web page and drop down a select box i can not see updated select list