# Get html element by title using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to get span tag from in response body where i have many html element.
Below is the span element which i have to find:

```html
 <span  title="WorldVentures Fdn" data- scribe="element:name">WorldVentures Fdn</span>      
<span  title="@WVFoundation" data-scribe="element:screen_name" >@WVFoundation</span>
```

I used this code:

```html
data.body = data.body.replace(/(<span[^c]*class="TweetAuthor-name Identity-name customisable-highlight"[^>]*>)/g, '');
```

This code is something fine only need to put closing tag for span also so closing tag with text still remains there.

How do i remove this span from complete body?

Comment: If you have HTML in a string and wish to manipulate it then use the DOM manipulation features of the browser, E.g. [How to parse HTML from an AJAX request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250434/parse-ajax-resposne-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: Alex, I tried this code var getSpan = div.querySelector("span.TweetAuthor-name Identity-name customisable-highlight"); getting null in getSpan variable.

Comment: This solution is fine for me: data.body = data.body.replace(/(<span[^c]*class="TweetAuthor-name Identity-name customisable-highlight"[^>]*>)/g, ''); but the issue here is i am not closing span tag in this regex so closing span tag with value still showing there. could you make this regex correct?

Comment: Don't use comments to post your code. Edit your question and put it there.

Comment: K thanks i am editing my question.