# Converting jQuery to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the jQuery code

```
success: function (html) {
         var text = $(html).text();
         if (text == '') {
            location.reload();
         } else {
            $("#warning2").html(html);

         }
 }
```

What I want is to convert `$(html).text();` to plain JavaScript

Here is my plain JavaScript code but the page will not reload unlike jQuery code.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
       {
       if (xhttp.responseText == "" || xhttp.responseText.textContent == "")
         location.reload();
       else
         document.getElementById("warning2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert jquery code to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript)

Comment: In this case, it's because the jQuery is parsing the HTML returned, then finding if there's any text within the elements parsed, whereas the JavaScript is testing if there's any HTML returned. To parse the HTML in plain JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32250434/215552.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description:

**"What I want is to convert $(html).text(); to plain JavaScript"**

So, I suppose you have a correct `ajax` function and your question is about converting that part of your code to `pure js`. (If you haven't it, you can check stackoverflow for links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) ).

Your code in `jquery`:

```
var text = $(html).text();
```

Same code in `js`:

```
var uDiv=document.createElement("div");
uDiv.innerHTML= xhttp.responseText;
var text=uDiv.children[0].innerText; //or .innerHTML
```

**tip:** in your last line (`.innerHTML=...`), if the response has script tags, you must separate them and create that script tags via code (similar my above code).

Comment: i change some of your codes to make it work. my failure was i did not build an element.

Comment: This was a trick. We don't append element to document never. I'm glad the problem solved.